# How to only underline the text when specifying the width?

Tags: c++, underline, fmt

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/color.h>
int main() {
    fmt::print(fmt::emphasis::underline, "{:<22}{:<8}{}\n", "Last Write Time", "Size", "Name");
}
```

[image: The text "Last Write Time Size Name" with everything underlined, including spaces]

The spaces are underlined. How to underline text only?

Comment: Don't output the space, just the word, turn off underline, output a space, then turn it back on?